# Fancybox jQuery Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, fancybox

I have a small situation. I am preparing a sample for a client and I cannot understand this. I have a div with 7 jpg's and a list item that is a link that if I click should fireup fancy box and show some pics in gallery format. Now this doesn't work so I remembered that I must add the '#' to the list of accepted characters in ci but still no problem, is there something I am doing wrong? here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){//js to handle fancybox

$('a#inline').fancybox({
    'overlayshow': true,
    'zoomSpeedIn': 400,
    'zoomSpeedOut': 400
} return false;);
});
//list link to fireup fancybox
<li><a id="inline" href="<?= "$base";?>home/photogallery">PhotoGallery</a></li>
```

then will several `<img />` that hold the images.

Any clues guys?

Comment: Why should you add '#' to accepted characters? The # refers to an ID of an element (in this case: it points to an A element with an ID of 'inline'). Is the fancybox showing without images? Are you getting JavaScript errors? Is the JS file loaded properly? 

More information would be good to help with this problem :)

Comment: fancy box shows but only the overlay. no box no images.